# sum of count of column for group by two columns mysql

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, sum

```
INSERT INTO tablex(Id, Name, Team, Joined) VALUES

(1, 'Mr. A', 'X', '2011-02-22'),

(2, 'Mr. B', 'Y', '2011-02-11'),

(3, 'Ms. C', 'X', '2011-02-10'),

(4, 'Mr. D', 'Y', '2011-01-12'),

(5, 'Ms. E', 'X', '2011-01-06'),

(6, 'Mr. F', 'Y', '2011-05-02');

(7, 'Mr. H', 'X', '2011-02-01');
```

output required is:

```
Month   | Team | TotalMembers | Percentage

 01/2011  | X    |   1          |   50

 01/2011  | Y    |   1          |   50

 02/2011  | X    |   2          |   75

 02/2011  | Y    |   1          |   25

 05/2011  | X    |   0          |   0

 05/2011  | Y    |   1          |   100
```

Please help me to do the above. Mostly preferred in MySQL (GROUP BY Team, DATE_FORMAT(Joined, '%m/%Y')). but can use PHP.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ca you explain the Percentage column? 

If it is, as I suppose it is, the ratio of members joined in one team to all members joined that month then rows 3 and 4 are not correct, should stay 66.6 and 33.3 ?

Comment: Is it necessary to have a 0 record for 5/11, team X? Won't that cause a lot of 0 records to appear in the output if you have another team, say team Z?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be more elegant solutions but this one should work:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( Joined, '%m/%Y' ) AS
    MONTH , team, (
    count( id ) / (
    SELECT count( * )
    FROM tablex
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT( Joined, '%m/%Y' ) = DATE_FORMAT( tx.Joined, '%m/%Y' )
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT( Joined, '%m/%Y' ) ) *100
    ) AS percentage
    FROM `tablex` AS tx
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT( Joined, '%m/%Y' ) , team
```

Comment: +1 Excellent answer! One minor issue though -- it doesn't include the 5/11 record for X that has 0 team members: http://sqlize.com/164lD5bwbw

Comment: But what if you have a team Z on 06/11, will you get a lot of records with 0's for X and Y? If you want that, you're looking at a whole different solution.First retreive all possible teams, then query the db for all the months. Then for each month calculate the total members and percentage and add 0 for non-existing teams. You could probably do it in one query but performance will be a disaster

Comment: I agree with you.  I'm just noting the discrepency between your solution and what the OP posted as the "required output".  I would take that concern up with the OP.

Comment: Thanks Nin! It was very useful. In continuation to this I've posted other query please have a look at this link. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753111/chart-in-excel-pdf-with-report-using-php)